# How to view user created table in OracleDB?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I created a table in my OracleDB, however when I use the command to view all tables in my environment, it gives a bunch of other tables, scrolling and filling my command prompt with lot of other tables.

Is there any other command to view just the tables that I created?

This is what I am doing currently

```
C:\> set ORACLE_SID=ocptech;
C:\> sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> CREATE TABLE customers  
     ( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,  
       customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,  
       city varchar2(50)  
     );  
SQL> SELECT table_name
     FROM user_tables
     ORDER BY table_name;
```

The above command gives me a lot of tables.

Also can someone also explain me, what these tablespace are while executing the following command

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLESPACES
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, I just noticed that you created your table while connected as SYS.  That's a big no-no.  In fact, you should not even be connected as SYS unless you absolutely need that elevated, unrestricted level of privilege.  Connecting as SYS is like walking a high-wire without a net, while juggling running chain saws.  In addition, by doing as you did, you created your table in the SYSTEM tablespace.  Read my earlier comments on that.

Comment: @Himanshu EdStevens has given you an excellent answer. If you have follow-up questions, please ask them separately. You *must not* cross post from Stack Overflow, as you did here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/67536275).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other command to view just the tables that I created?

If you know the table name just add it in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT table_name
     FROM user_tables
     where upper(table_name) = 'MY_NEW_TABLE'
     ORDER BY table_name;
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
select owner,
       object_name
from dba_objects
where object_type = 'TABLE'
  and created_date > trunc(to_date('05-15-2021','dd-mm-yyyy'))
  order by owner,
           object_name;
```

> Also can someone also explain me, what these tablespace are while
> executing the following command

- `SYSTEM` is where the data dictionary lives.  Don't touch it. Don't create your own objects in it.
- `SYSAUX` is an auxiliary to `SYSTEM`.  Treat it the same.
- `UNDOTBS1` is where oracle writes 'undo' information - information needed to rollback a transaction.  Not only used for actual rollback, but when a query needs a transactionally-consistent view of the data.
- `TEMP` is the 'temp' tablespace.  Used when operations like sorting cannot be completed in memory.  Kind of like Oracle's version of the OS's page file.
- `USERS` - created by oracle by default to be the default tablespace assigned to users.

More information can be found in the [Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/index.html) manual.

-Expanding original answer to address additional questions:

> So where my user created tables are stored, I mean in which
> tablespace?

If you did not specify the TS when you created the table, it will be in the default TS for the user that created it.   You can check this with

```
select username,
       default_tablespace
from dba_users
order by username
;
```

To check specifically for which TS a table is in:

```
select owner,
       table_name,
       tablespace_name
from dba_tables
order by owner,
         table_name
;
```

> What if there are 100 of user created tables, how do I view in that
> case of course I can't filter by table name in that case

Then remove the WHERE clause, and (if using sqlplus) spool the output to a text file, which you then open with a text editor:

```
spool myfile.txt
select .....
spool off
```

Comment: Does that mean user created database are under USERS? Also object are same as databases right?

Comment: NO!  There's no such concept (in oracle) of a "user created database".  The database is created by user SYS.  Objects are not the same thing as database.  Objects are "objects" that are _within_ the database.  Objects are things like table spaces, tables, indexes, procedures, triggers, etc.  Tablespaces are logical abstractions of data files, and tables, indexes, partitions (collectively known as 'segments') are stored in tablespaces.  USERS is just one of several default tablespaces mentioned earlier.  It is the _default_ tablespace for user/application segments .... (cont) ...

Comment: ... cont ...  Typically when an application is designed/created, the DBA will create a new tablespace specifically for that app.  But in the end a given schema/user can have objects in multiple tablespaces, and a given tablespace can have objects from multiple users/schema.   Please go spend some time in the concepts manual, linked earlier.